# What is the header file called to create generic classes using bloodshed dev-c++?

Tags: c++, class, generics, header

I have tried using `#include <generic>` and  `#include <generic.h>` but these are not recognised. I have tried consulting the manual but it does not help me.

So anyone know the correct name for this header file using Bloodshed Dev-C++?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "generic classes"? C++ has no feature named like that. Or do you mean a class called "generic" from some 3rd party library?

Comment: A generic class is itself a macro that generates classes that all have the same general form

Comment: That's not how generic programming is done in C++. Where have you seen this before?

Comment: @Mr_leighman: What made you think there is such a header, or such a set of macros in C++?

Comment: Well, In my text book it says so...and it says "consult this file and your system manual to determine all macros supplied in your generic.h"

Comment: Also, doesn't Dev-C++ use an ancient C++ compiler? You'd be better off using a modern IDE and compiler. You can get Visual Studio 11 beta for free and it's great.

Comment: @Mr_leighman: Does it maybe refer to a file that comes with the textbook, where some of the textbook code is given to you?

Comment: @blame53 Programming in c++ by Paul M.Chirlian

Comment: @blame53 - No code with textbook included on disk!!

Comment: Yes - there are of course example code using the macro generic code included.

Comment: @Mr_leighman: If it is the same book I know, it is from 1990, doesn't know about templates, and is talking about its own header. Dump it. It is 22 years (!) older than the latest C++ standard. It contains nothing useful at all. It will only make things worse. What was considered C++ back then is now something totally different.

Comment: Well o.k then..That's news to me. I guess its something I should of checked before I started the book. I found the book easy to absorb and understand now I have to start all over again after 8 months of studying this book!!!- because you're saying its totally out of date. Great,  Now - I think I will go and smoke a Hamlet cigar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't have generics like Java and C# do. C++ has a similar feature called *templates*, but there are no special headers to include for that. C++ supports templates *intrinsically*. You can use template types and functions by mentioning their names, along with the template argument type in angle brackets:

```
#include <vector>

// declare a variable of type std::vector<int>
std::vector<int> vector_of_ints;
```

The `#include <vector>` is to tell the compiler about the `std::vector` template class, not to tell the compiler how to use templates in general.

You can define new template types and functions with the `template` keyword:

```
// declare a function accepting and returning a type to be determined later
template <typename T>
T add_one(T x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

Comment: I would say templates have a use case that's similar to generics in Java and C#, but that doesn't make templates similar to Java/C# generics.

Comment: Yes Thanks, I will try some variations with the help of your answer - not sure how to translate your answer to my answer but I am sure it will help, thanks

Comment: Well o.k then..That's news to me. I guess its something I should of checked before I started the book. I found the book easy to absorb and understand now I have to start all over again after 8 months of studying this book!!!- because you're saying its totally out of date. Great,  Now - I think I will go and smoke a Hamlet cigar!

Answer (score 3):

`<generic.h>` is a header from ancient, pre-standard C++. In fact it's old even compared to pre-standard C++. I was used back when C++ was just a precompiler on top of C. Even if you could find a compiler that still supported this, using it would not be a good idea and you would not be learning C++ as it exists today.

Any book that mentions `<generic.h>` is probably twenty years out of date. Instead you should choose a book from [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/365496). If you're just learning to program I recommend *Programming: Principals and Practice Using C++*. If you're already familiar with programming in other languages then *Accelerated C++* should be good.

The latest version of Dev-C++ is very old as well (though not nearly as old as `<generic.h>`) and newer, much better, compilers and IDEs are available for free. If you're on Windows then Visual Studio 11 beta should be your first choice. (assuming you're not also on an ancient version of Windows...)

Comment: Just FYI, there have actually been some [recent independent updates](http://orwellengine.blogspot.com/) to Dev-C++. But yeah, I would still not recommend it over any of the alternatives.

Comment: Well o.k then..That's news to me. I guess its something I should of checked before I started the book. I found the book easy to absorb and understand now I have to start all over again after 8 months of studying this book!!!- because you're saying its totally out of date. Great,  Now - I think I will go and smoke a Hamlet cigar!